# Error on pom.xml with Light Admin

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, lightadmin

I got the error on below code of pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.lightadmin</groupId>
        <artifactId>lightadmin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

The error message is as below :

```
Missing artifact org.lightadmin:lightadmin:jar:1.0.0.M3-SNAPSHOT
```

Please advice on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look up for the available `lightadmin` dependency versions in [mvn repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.lightadmin/lightadmin). Version `1.0.0.M3-SNAPSHOT` is not listed here

You can use version `1.2.0.RC1` by specifying a different value in the `version` tag as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lightadmin</groupId>
    <artifactId>lightadmin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RC1</version>
</dependency>
```